# Cloning entities

Tags: entities

i have 3 different entities build with help of EntityApi module. They connected with each other with ID column  in tables.

```
Entity - "Purchase"
Entity - "Catalog" has 'purchase_id' column in table
Entity - "Product" has 'catalog_id' column in its table.
```

What is the way to clone in one click some already active "Purchase" with all catalogs and product which it ccontains?

Answer (score 1):

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3AcreateDuplicate/8.2.x

Check that out. You can use it by doing something like:

```
// Load the entity you want.
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
 ->getStorage('my_entity')
 ->load('1');

// Copy it.
$duplicate = $entity->createDuplicate();
$duplicate->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [node_clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone) can [clone entities and their fields for you](http://drupal.org/node/1513812). There is an API to call it programmatically, or if you have Admin pages created for your entity I believe you can make a "save and clone" or "clone" button show up there.

Comment: Both not good for me. Lets say i have in purchase 3 catalogs with 100 products in each. Clone one by one manually not the way to do it. I would like to have script which will do it automaticcaly.

Comment: what? node_clone clones the 1 entity and any sub-data as well.  If you want to script it write a small php script (I did not small Module) and run that script via Drush. Or, make a module and use like views_bulk_operations module and node_clone. If you're cloning *anything* node_clone is the way to go. Good luck finding another approach ...

Comment: Thank you i will check node_clone more thoughrely may be i missed  something.